# how to integrate keyboard actions with mytoolkit datagrid in uwp

Tags: .net, xaml, datagrid, uwp, mytoolkit

I am working on a uwp app. In that I am using a data grid from https://github.com/MyToolkit/MyToolkit/wiki/DataGrid here. Now in this I have to use keyboard actions using up and down arrows.

I have used KeyDown event and selection_changed event for first item only keydown event is firing. then selection_changed event is firing when up and down arrow keys pressed.
 But I want to do some action when enter key pressed after selecting a row in the grid. 
the code I have used is:`

```
 private void dgsuggestion_KeyDown(object sender, KeyRoutedEventArgs e)

        {
            if (e.Key == Windows.System.VirtualKey.Enter)
            {

            }
        }

        private void dgsuggestion_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            ProductsList res= (ProductsList)((MyToolkit.Controls.DataGrid)sender).SelectedItem;
            selectedsku = res;
        }`
```

Can anyone help me..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The events get absorb by either the system or the control, so you have to attach the event manually using `AddHandler`.

```
MyToolkit.Controls.DataGrid myGrid; // this is your grid

// Do this
myGrid.AddHandler(KeyDownEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(dgsuggestion_KeyDown), true);

// Not this
myGrid.KeyDown += dgsuggestion_KeyDown;
```

Here's an explanation of how it works.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms598899(v=vs.110).aspx